# Why am I getting an infinite loop in my useEffect (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Basically I have a function called getWeatherForecast which gets some weather data from an api however, I am getting an infinite loop and it keeps requesting for the data an infinite number of times.

Here is my function

```
 const getWeatherForecast = async () => {
    const weatherForecast = await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${props.latitude}&lon=${props.longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
    console.log(weatherForecast)
    setWeatherDetails(weatherForecast)
}
```

This is how I used the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    getWeatherForecast()
    // console.log(`This is the forecast ${weatherDetails}`)
 } , [getWeatherForecast])
```

Any idea why I am getting an infinite loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because  this:

```
getWeatherForecast
```

is a function which gets recreated on each render.
Inside that function you are calling a `setWeatherDetails`, which triggers a render. Hence on the next render a new instance of that function is created, which is different from the previous one, and `useEffect` is called again.
Wrap that function in [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

```
let getWeatherForecast = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const weatherForecast = await axios.get(
      `${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${props.latitude}&lon=${props.longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`
    );
    console.log(weatherForecast);
    setWeatherDetails(weatherForecast);
  }, [
    /*
     * put the dependencies here
     * if API_ENDPOINT and API_KEY are defined outside the component no need to put them as dependency
     */
    props.latitude,
    props.longitude,
  ]);
```

But If I remember correctly linter may complain about dependency like `props.latitude` and suggest to assign it to some variable before the `useCallback`, and then use that as a dependency like:

```
let latitude  = props.latitude; // then use latitude as dependency
```

Comment: Do you mind showing me how? I do not clearly understand how I should wrap it in a useCallBack

Comment: @HadiZouhbi Check update

Comment: When I add weatherDetails to the dependency of the callback I get an infinite loop and when I do not add it, I get back an empty object as my weatherDetails state

Comment: @HadiZouhbi did you add the `getWeatherForecast`  which was returned by `useCallback` as dependency?

Comment: const getWeatherForecast = useCallback( async () => {
    const weatherForecast = await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
    setWeatherDetails(weatherForecast)
    console.log(weatherDetails)
},
[API_ENDPOINT , API_KEY , latitude , longitude , weatherDetails]) This is what my code looks like now and in the useEffect the dependency is getWeatherForecast

Comment: @HadiZouhbi why did you add `weatherDetails` as dependency?

Comment: Because I am setting the state in there , doesn't that require me to add it as a dependency or it will be still empty even after setting it

Comment: @HadiZouhbi You are not using it inside the `useCallback` are you (remove the `console.log`)? Then you should not add it as dependency. Read the docs of `useCallback` for more info

Comment: I am assigning it in the callback , if you watch carefully right under the console.log I set it.

Comment: @HadiZouhbi setting it doesn't mean *using* it. You are *reading* it only inside `console.log`, remove the log and it won't be needed as dependency

Comment: When I did that and I then see what is inside weatherDetails it gives me [object , object]

Comment: @HadiZouhbi I helped you with infinite loop problem, if you followed all steps infinite loop problem had to disappear. If you are having another problem, you should ask a new question.